# writeFile function using output from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, writefile

When ran, the below code works in a stand alone project. However, how would I modify the code if I wanted to replace the variable "sample_text" with an output in the terminal as opposed to already an array in the code? For instance, say the output looks like "student: danny, age: 28, weight: 148" when running node in another file.

```
 // writefile.js

 const fs = require('fs');

 let sample_text = 'student: danny, age: 28, weight: 148'

 // write to a new file named sample.json

 fs.writeFile('sample.json', sample_text, (err) => {  
                if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Text saved!');
            });
```

Comment: Export a function and call it from somewhere else?

Comment: "... replace the variable "sample_text" with an output in the terminal" - do you want to take user input from the terminal when this file is run with `node filename.js`?

Comment: @ack_inc yes, that is the hope. I run node index.js, and then selenium runs and outputs a bunch of data in the terminal. My hope is to get all that data into a json file. (I accidentally put txt in the example, but actually want a json file).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Enter data', (data) => {

  fs.writeFile('2pac.txt', data, (err) => {  
            if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Text saved!');
        });

  rl.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be doing two things:

1. piping the output of selenium webdriver to the node program
2. listening for the 'data' event on process.stdin to capture selenium's output

Your node program should look something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = "";

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

process.stdin.on('data', chunk => {
  // I'm just collecting the chunks into 'data',
  //   but you might choose to do some processing here
  data += chunk;
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  // do some more processing here, if needed
  fs.writeFileSync('output.json', data);
});
```

And you should start selenium and this node program by running this command from the terminal:
`selenium-webdriver | node index.js`